# SQL: Select a row only if that cell has the max value given the ID

Tags: sql

I realize the title of the question is much more difficult than the question itself.

Basically I have a dataset like this one:

```
ID  Hour
01  1
01  2
01  3
02  1
02  2
03  1
03  2
03  3
03  4
```

The dataset refers to people that are playing a game. ID is, of course, the ID of the subject whilst 'Hour' refers to what happened in that hour of game. Now, I would like to **select only the rows that refer to the last hour played by that player**.

So that:

```
ID  Hour
01  3
02  2
03  4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use `MAX()`

```
SELECT ID, MAX(HOUR) Max_hour
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY ID
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution

SELECT ID, MAX(HOUR) as Maxhour
FROM   Table1
GROUP  BY ID

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you actually want to select *other* columns on the same row, then the simple `group by`/`max` solution doesn't quite work.

One solution that works in any database that supports window functions is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by hour desc) as seqnum
      from TableName t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

OR, if you want to make it more complicated as it is^^ this is the way to go:

select *
from tablename t1
where t.hour = (select max(hour) from tablename t2 where t2.id = t1.id)